# Tool to extract specific data from a Oracle database (with over 100 tables) to another Oracle Database which has the structure but not the data

Tags: oracle, data-migration, sql-data-tools

I have the following challenge:
I have a large **Oracle Database #** 1 with 100 tables which are linked through one to many and many to many relationship.

I need to copy only certain rows from the main **Oracle Database # 1**  into a **Oracle Database #2** which has the same data structure ( tables) but no data.
Is there a tool that helps me automate the load process, taking into account the constraints that arise from one-many and many-many relationships.

Answer (score 2):

It is a relatively simple task to "copy" **all** the data. How? Using Export/Import Data Pump (or even the original exp/imp utilities).

Although you can apply the `WHERE` clause to export, I'm not sure that doing that for 100 tables is feasible. You should know how tables are related to each other so that you wouldn't miss a record.

So, if you're about to do it table-by-table, perhaps it is a better option to write (PL/)SQL code which will do the job. A procedure, maybe? Using an `IN` parameter, you'd be able to copy any set-of-records you want. Of course, you'd have to maintain the procedure if new tables are created or relationships are modifed.